# Transforming a Fourier series into another expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

**Problem**
[image]

**Fourier Series**

[image]

**Solution**

From the solution manual, they said:

Note that $f(1)=L=2$. Therefore:
$$ f(1) = 2 = \frac{2}{2} + \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{sin((2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2})}{2n+1}$$

**Question**

The solution seems very arbitrary- you just take a random guess that $f(1)=L=2$. How do you know that $f(1)=L=2$ and how do they know to set $n=0$ in the summation? Is there a more intuitive way to get the answer above?

Comment: "My work" + "from the solution manual" ???

Comment: okay i changed it to Solution. Do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: The value of $f(1)$ comes from the definition of $f(x)$ (the function that you obtain a Fourier series representation for) which you have explicitly left out but the question in the picture refers to a square wave. The value of $L$ comes from knowing the period of the square wave, which again, depends on knowing $f(x)$....

Answer (score 0):

> **OP question**: "Is there a more intuitive way to get the answer above ?".

$$
\mbox{Maybe, ( a "non Fourier" one )}\quad{\pi \over 4} = \int_{0}^{1}{\mathrm{d}x \over x^{2} + 1} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(\,-1\right)^{n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,\mathrm{d}x =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\left(\,-1\right)^{n} \over 2n + 1}
$$